# How do you evaluate $\int \frac{y^2}{y^2+d^2}dy$?

Tags: integration

$\color{green}{question}$:

How do you evaluate this integral?

> $$\int \frac{y^2}{y^2+d^2}dy=y-d\,{\tan}^{-1}\left ( \frac{y}{d} \right )+\mathrm{constant}$$

$\color{green}{I~know}$ I should use the change of variables, But I do not know how to do.

Thank you for any hint.

Comment: Start by adding $d^2-d^2$ to the numerator.

Comment: @L.F. thanks for edit.your edit was really helpful :)

Comment: @Software: $\ddot\smile +1$

Comment: @BabakS. thank you :) your comment give me incentive for more activities.

Comment: As a general rule, if you want to integrate the quotient of two polynomials where the degree of the numerator is at least as large as the degree of the denominator, then you want to divide first.

Comment: @user84413 yes,is true.thank you so much.

Comment: @amWhy thank you my friend

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**

- $$\frac{y^2}{y^2+d^2}=\frac{y^2+d^2-d^2}{y^2+d^2}=1-\frac{d^2}{y^2+d^2}$$
- $$\frac{d^2}{y^2+d^2}=\frac{1}{(y/d)^2+1}=\frac{1}{t^2+1}$$
- $$\int\frac{dt}{t^2+1}=\arctan t+C$$

Comment: thanks for your hint $\Large\color{red}{+}$

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I think this is the best answer so $\huge\color{green}{✓}$ for you :) thank you again.

Answer (score 6):

$$\frac{y^2}{y^2+d^2} = \frac{y^2 + d^2}{y^2+d^2} - \frac{d^2}{y^2+d^2}$$

The latter is an arctangent integral.

Comment: thank you, Excellent. $\Large\color{blue}{+}$

Answer (score 0):

Maple code with(Student[Calculus1]):IntTutor$(y^2/(y^2 +d^2),y$); produced the output which can be seen [here](http://rapidshare.com/files/1020936765/screen2.24.08.13.docx). It coincides with the excellent answer by Eric Auld.

Comment: thank you, This code is useful for me so +1 for you. :)

Comment: It would be preferred to insert the document linked as a image in your answer itself.